# How to know if a date is in an interval using lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate, tidyverse

If I have a lubridate interval: `"2010-02-20" %--% "2012-03-15"`
How may I know if a date, say `"2011-01-12"`, is in that range?

I am using lubridate and the tidyverse packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ymd("2011-01-12") %within% ("2010-02-20" %--% "2012-03-15")

# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table) 
ymd("2011-01-12") %between% c("2010-02-20", "2012-03-15")

library(dplyr)
between(ymd("2011-01-12"), "2010-02-20", "2012-03-15")
```